# How to format multiline text for easy pasting into a Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets, clipboard, copy-paste

I have multiline text like this:

```
- foo
- "bar"
- baz\n
- 'hello world'
```

I am copying this from [ag-grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/) spreadsheet cells (it shouldn't matter that I'm using ag-grid for this question, but just know that I need to figure out how to format the text I get from that cell), which looks like this:

[image]

I tried formatting the text from that right column to be like this:

```
const copyText = (value?: string): string => {
  return `"${(value ?? '').replace(/"/gm, '\\"')}"`;
};
```

I get this when pasting it in the Google Spreadsheet:

[image]

How do I need to format the text so I can paste the multiple lines into a **single spreadsheet cell**? I added `\n` and `"` and `'` characters in the multiline to just show that the multiline can contain any text basically, so it shouldn't mess up if they include quotes and backslashes and such. I want this basically:

[image]

When I copy from the ag-grid, the clipboard pastes this essentially:

```
L1\t"- foo
- \"bar\"
- baz\n
- 'hello world'
"
```

So what am I doing wrong in formatting.

Comment: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/27113/pasting-text-with-line-breaks-into-google-sheets-populates-multiple-cells seems to say it's not possible to copy multiple cells (some including multiline text, others just single-line text (like "L1" in my example). Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use double double quotes:

```
L1\t"- foo
- ""bar""
- baz\n
- 'hello world'
"
```